# Leaflet: Draw a .gpx path with line and arrow both styled

Tags: leaflet

I'm a bit new to leaflet, but I have spend hours without being able to solve this problem: I want to draw a line with arrows using a gpx file as source. This should be in a layer that can be displayed or not usin overlay.
I manage to style either the arrow or the line, but I did not manage to style both. Here is my code:
Can anyone give me advices on how to style the line ?
Many thanks.

```
var customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
   L.polylineDecorator(layer, {
      patterns: [   
        {offset: 25, repeat: 15, symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({pixelSize: 10, pathOptions: {stroke: false, color: '#000', fillOpacity: 1, weight: 0}})}
      ]
    }).addTo(customLayer);  /// Adds each decorator to the map!!!!
  } 
}
);

var runLayer = omnivore.gpx('./FerneyGex.gpx', null, customLayer);
    controlLayers2.addOverlay(runLayer, 'Ferney - Gex');
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I tried many things without succeding, mostly by adding style to the layer afterwards, but then it takes the new style but ignore the arrows. I understand the code above adds arrows, but I do not seen where the default style for the lines drawns comes from and how i can superseed it...

Comment: I did it with a trick, by superposing 2 offseted dash with the arrowHead. Not really clean, but working...:

Comment: {offset: 12, repeat: 30, symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({pixelSize: 8, pathOptions: {stroke: true, color: '#000', fillOpacity: 0, weight: 2}})},
                        { offset: 15, repeat: 30, symbol: L.Symbol.dash({pixelSize: 15, pathOptions: {color: '#f00', weight: 2}}) },
                { offset: 0, repeat: 30, symbol: L.Symbol.dash({pixelSize: 15, pathOptions: {color: '#f00', weight: 2}}) }